# Getting list of SVN users for Subversion -> Git migration?

Tags: git, svn

I've been looking over a few SVN -> Git migrations and they all mention getting a proper users list before migrating, specifically by using the command:

```
svn log -q | grep -e '^r' | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "|" } ; { print $2 }' | sort | uniq
```

I have access to the Ubuntu server hosting the single repository (with 9 projects), but no SVN installation locally. Is it possible to run that command on the server to get the list of usernames? At the moment it just gives back the error:

```
svn: E155007: '/var/subversion/' is not a working copy
```

Comment: It could be nice if you mentioned where you found this command in the first place.

Comment: Think I originally got it from here: http://technology.mattrude.com/2011/10/importing-a-svn-repo-into-git/

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Pass the path to the repository as a URL:

```
svn log -q file:///var/subversion | grep -e '^r' | awk -F '|' '{ print $2 }' | sort | uniq
```

By the way, if you need the list of authors in chronological order of first commit (I found it helpful once when converting from svn to git), you can do the following:

```
svn log -q -r 1:HEAD url://to/repo | grep '^r' | awk -F'|' '!x[$2]++{print$2}'
```

Answer (score 6):

See the instructions below to convert an SVN repository to a git repository

Note: *To ONLY see the list of users run line item 1.*

**CONVERT SVN REPO to GIT REPO**

**1. Retrieve a list of all Subversion committers**

```
 $ svn log -q https://svn.example.com/repository_name | awk -F '|' '/^r/ {sub("^ ", "", $2); sub(" $", "", $2); print $2" = "$2" <"$2">"}' | sort -u > authors-transform.txt
```

That will grab all the log messages, pluck out the usernames, eliminate any duplicate usernames, sort the usernames and place them into a "authors-transform.txt” file. Now edit each line in the file. For example, convert:

```
username = username <username>
```

into this:

```
 username = Firstname Lastname <username@example.com>
```

**2. Clone the Subversion repository using git-svn**

```
git svn clone [SVN repo URL] --no-metadata -A authors-transform.txt --stdlayout ~/temp
```

**3. Convert svn:ignore properties to .gitignore**
If your svn repo was using svn:ignore properties, you can easily convert this to a .gitignore file using:

```
cd ~/temp
git svn show-ignore > .gitignore
git add .gitignore
git commit -m 'Convert svn:ignore properties to .gitignore.'
```

**4. Push repository to a bare git repository**
First, create a bare repository and make its default branch match svn’s "trunk” branch name.

```
git init --bare ~/new-bare.git
cd ~/new-bare.git
git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/trunk

cd ~/temp
git remote add bare ~/new-bare.git
git config remote.bare.push 'refs/remotes/*:refs/heads/*'
git push bare
```

You can now safely delete the ~/temp repository.

**5. Rename "trunk" branch to "master"**
Your main development branch will be named "trunk” which matches the name it was in Subversion. You’ll want to rename it to Git’s standard "master” branch using:

```
cd ~/new-bare.git
git branch -m trunk master
```

**6. Clean up branches and tags**
git-svn makes all of Subversions tags into very-short branches in Git of the form "tags/name”. You’ll want to convert all those branches into actual Git tags using:

```
cd ~/new-bare.git
git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' refs/heads/tags |
cut -d / -f 4 |
while read ref
do
   git tag "$ref" "refs/heads/tags/$ref";
   git branch -D "tags/$ref";
done
```

**7. Move bare repository to central remote repository**
Example of how to move your local bare repository to a gitolite repository:

```
mv new-bare.git repository_name.git
tar czvf repository_name.git.tar.gz repository_name.git/
scp repository_name.git.tar.gz remote_host:
ssh remote_host
tar xzvf repository_name.git.tar.gz
sudo chown -R git:staff repository_name.git/
cd repository_name.git/
find . -type f -exec chmod go= {} \;  # remove group and world permissions
find . -type d -exec chmod go= {} \;  # remove group and world permissions
cd ../
mv repository_name.git /Users/git/repositories/
```

**8. Clone new local copy**

```
mv old-svn-copy old-svn-copy.backup
git clone git@remote_host:repository_name.git
```

List all unversioned files from your old local svn repository and copy them to the new local git repository:

```
cd old-svn-copy.backup
git clean -dXn  # Using this command because the old copy was a git-svn clone
cp example-file.txt ../repository_name/  # copy all files and directories from the list that you need in the new local git repository
```

You can now move the local svn copy backup to your trash. It might be a good idea not to empty your trash until your sure everything is working correctly.

**9. Done.**

Source [here](https://gist.github.com/epicserve/1219858/9f30d5ffca7d6b6e4130c4b9b300b8167c868a5f)